# How to properly boot ISO9660 looped image with latest GRUB versions?

Tags: grub2, grub, iso, loop-device

I'm trying to boot Ubuntu live ISO9660 image with GRUB 2.04 using [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot). It is failing to boot with GRUB error `error: unknown filesystem`, even though I can browse as well the boot partition as the looped image filesystem from GRUB. I'm using the following commands to boot:

```
set isofile="/boot/ubuntu-18.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso"
loopback loop $isofile
linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$isofile noprompt noeject
initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
```

I've also tried a few different live ISOs of different distros with no success. What am I doing wrong? Were there any changes recently introduced in GRUB that require some changes to the above commands?

Comment: There is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1851311), that affects boot Ubuntu live ISO9660 image with GRUB 2.04.  Some alteratives/workarounds are discussed in comments to the [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1851311).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately it is stated in the comments that BIOS setups work and only UEFI ones doesn't (I have a BIOS one) and they also don't mention the "unknown filesystem" bug. However, they link to a more similar recent [GRUB bug report](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?57322).

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link to that recent grub bug report.